# Retornar Data mais recente por Coluna?

Tags: mysql

Tenho esta tabela em `MariaDB [contas]>

```
SELECT * FROM mercado WHERE nome_mercado LIKE 'extra';
```

---

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| id | nome_mercado | data_compra | produto   | descricao | preco |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | Extra        | 2017-07-12  | Coca Cola | Coca      |  3.00 |
|  2 | Extra        | 2017-07-12  | Sucos     | Suco      |  3.50 |
|  3 | Extra        | 2017-07-12  | Frios     | Frios     |  7.80 |
| 11 | extra        | 2017-07-28  | Suco      | Teste     |  5.90 |
| 12 | extra        | 2017-07-28  | Bolacha   |           |  2.49 |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+`
```

Gostaria que me retornasse apenas os produtos com as datas mais recente, ou seja, apenas estes:

```
| 11 | extra        | 2017-07-28  | Suco      | Teste     |  5.90 |
| 12 | extra        | 2017-07-28  | Bolacha   |           |  2.49 |
```

Usei este select, porem não retorna nada:

MariaDB [contas]>

```
SELECT * FROM mercado WHERE nome_mercado LIKE 'extra' = 
  (SELECT data_compra FROM mercado ORDER BY data_compra DESC LIMIT 1);

Empty set, 5 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quiser sempre os itens da última compra faça assim:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  MERCADO 
where 
  NOME_MERCADO like 'extra'
  and DATA_COMPRA = 
  (
      select 
        max(DATA_COMPRA) 
      from 
        MERCADO 
      where 
        NOME_MERCADO like 'extra'
  )
```

É isto que você queria?

#### Exemplo sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc427d/1

Comment: Era exatamente isso. Grato!

Comment: Essa subquery que você colocou não seria inutil? Ao meu ver ela pode ser simplificada por apenas: `max(DATA_COMPRA)`

Comment: @Francisco você tem que fazer outra pesquisa mesmo. Sua ideia aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebfb84/3 e o correto aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc427d/1

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar um `WHERE` pare retornar os resultados dos últimos 3 dias, por exemplo:

```
WHERE data_compra >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

Caso seja mais tempo, só você editar o intervalo.

A *query* abaixo retorna todas os resultados que tenha o `nome_mercado` como `extra` e os últimos registros dos últimos 3 dias. Veja:

```
SELECT * FROM mercado WHERE nome_mercado LIKE 'extra' AND data_compra >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY ORDER BY data_compra DESC
```

Comment: Eu colocaria este Where no segundo select?, após o "=" ?

Comment: @user54154 veja a edição.

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa de subquery, só fazer tudo junto:

```
SELECT * FROM mercado WHERE nome_mercado LIKE 'extra' ORDER BY data_compra DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Se a última compra tiver 3 itens? Faz o que?

Comment: @MarlonTiedt Eu estou respondendo o que é pedido na pergunta. Por ela não se sabe se existe essa variável.